# The meaning of 'for' here

Tags: conjunctions

> In fact, that morning, as Mr. MacPherson hesitated on a scalp of
>   glittering white ice, there were already three Gentiles in the school
>   (that is to say, Anglo-Saxons; ***for*** Ukrainians, Poles, and Yugoslavs,
>   with funny names and customs of their own, did not count as true
>   Gentiles), and ten years hence F.F.H.S would no longer be the Jewish
>   high school.
>
> -The Apprenticeship of Duddy Kravitz by Mordecai Richler -

Can I take '***for***' here to mean 'because'?

Comment: You could look this up in any dictionary: [**for** *conj* because, since](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/for).

Comment: @Robusto I did but I wasn't sure.

Comment: @Robusto: When the number of definitions *for* a single word hits the high double digits, it's no longer terribly practical to require learners to find the one or two applicable ones before being allowed to ask here.

Comment: I'm really glad you got an answer you liked so quickly, but you might want to wait a while before selecting an answer. This post on meta explains some reasons why: [Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1307/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, *for* means *[because](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/for#Conjunction)*.

**Edit:**

I have been playing with the words in my head, trying to delineate the exact differences between *for* and *because*.  All I have come up with are

First, *for* has a more elegant, even pompous sound to it.  The King James Version of the Bible renders Mark 5:9 as

> And he asked him, What is thy name? And he answered, saying, My name is Legion: for we are many.

Most newer translations have kept the "for", but the New Living Translate goes with

> Then Jesus demanded, "What is your name?" And he replied, "My name is Legion, because there are many of us inside this man."

Clearer, of course, especially to a young or ESL reader, but the *power* of the passage is lost.

Also, the word *for* -- in part, I think, because of its primary sense of purpose or intention -- carries a stronger notion of causality.  "A because B" literally means "B is the cause of A"  but perhaps only in a simple, unexceptional way ("I ate because I was hungry.")

"A for B" suggests "A, unlikely and unintuitive though it is, really happened and it only happened owing to B." ("I would die for her, for I love her with all my heart.")

Does that help?

> "I'm not lost for I know where I am."
>   -- A.A. Milne
>
> "I am determined to be cheerful and happy in whatever situation I may find myself, for I have learned that the greater part of our misery or unhappiness is determined not by our circumstance but by our disposition."
>   -- Martha Washington
>
> "Yea, though I walk through the valley of the shadow of death, I will fear no evil, for Thou art with me."
>   -- Psalm 23:4 (KJV again)

When in doubt, use "because".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the preposition **for** can introduce a clause of explanation or clarification, which gives it a meaning very close to **because**.

There is an implicit "he counted only three *even though there were apparently more*" and the *for*-clause explains the discrepancy.

**for** could also be paraphrased with **since** or **inasmuch as**.

Here, the *for*-clause not only *explains* the discrepancy, it *identifies* it.  Had the passage said "he counted *only* three...", then we would have been tipped off earlier about the discrepancy.  The discrepancy emerges when he begins to qualify what he means by "Gentiles"..."that is to say, Anglo-Saxons; **for**...".